# Cassandra order issues

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, cql

I encounter a problem sorting data on Cassandra using `CLUSTERING ORDER BY`.
The returned data is not sorted as expected with the following conf:

Any idea why the result is not sorted as expected ?

```
CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS foo WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : '1' };

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo.keyword (
keyword_id int,
keyword_text text,
PRIMARY KEY (keyword_text, keyword_id)
)WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY(keyword_id DESC);
```

I add 5 records

```
INSERT INTO foo.keyword (keyword_id, keyword_text) VALUES (1,'bar1');
INSERT INTO foo.keyword (keyword_id, keyword_text) VALUES (2,'bar2');
INSERT INTO foo.keyword (keyword_id, keyword_text) VALUES (3,'bar3');
INSERT INTO foo.keyword (keyword_id, keyword_text) VALUES (4,'bar4');
INSERT INTO foo.keyword (keyword_id, keyword_text) VALUES (5,'bar5');
```

And SELECT :

```
SELECT keyword_id FROM foo.keyword;
```

Obtained result :

```
2
4
3
1
5
```

Expected :

```
5
4
3
2
1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any idea why the result is not sorted as expected ?

Yes. Cassandra supports ordering *within* a partition. When data is SELECTed *without* a WHERE clause, the result set is returned in order of the hashed token values of the partition key. In this case, the partition key is `keyword_text`.

Let's try altering that SELECT to execute the `token` function on `keyword_text`:

```
SELECT keyword_id, token(keyword_text) FROM foo.keyword;

 keyword_id | system.token(keyword_text)
------------+----------------------------
          2 |       -5699002630445609302
          4 |       -5246443235113384067
          3 |        1880591418861795474
          1 |        7350118602498431585
          5 |        7355007313553950035

(5 rows)
```

As we can see, the order is indeed indicated by the hashed token value of `keyword_text`. So, that's why the results are returned in this particular order.

Ok, so how do we fix it? Well, we'll need to choose a different partition key. I'm not sure about the underlying use case here, so we'll just use today's date to "bucket" the data into a partition named `day_bucket`.

```
CREATE TABLE keyword (
  day_bucket int,
  keyword_id int,
  keyword_text TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (day_bucket, keyword_id)
) WITH CLUSTerING ORDER BY (keyword_id DESC);
```

Next, we'll INSERT some data:

```
INSERT INTO keyword (day_bucket, keyword_id, keyword_text) VALUES (20240502, 1,'bar1');
INSERT INTO keyword (day_bucket, keyword_id, keyword_text) VALUES (20240502, 2,'bar2');
INSERT INTO keyword (day_bucket, keyword_id, keyword_text) VALUES (20240502, 3,'bar3');
INSERT INTO keyword (day_bucket, keyword_id, keyword_text) VALUES (20240502, 4,'bar4');
INSERT INTO keyword (day_bucket, keyword_id, keyword_text) VALUES (20240502, 5,'bar5');
```

And then rerun our query using today's date in the WHERE clasue:

```
SELECT keyword_id FROM keyword WHERE day_bucket = 20240502;

 keyword_id
------------
          5
          4
          3
          2
          1

(5 rows)
```

Note that we shouldn't put all data into a single partition. That's not good for data distribution and will lead to unbound partition growth. The idea, is to find a partition key that works well with the use case.

Comment: FWIW, I actually wrote a blog post (9 years ago) about how to properly enforce sort order in Cassandra: https://www.datastax.com/blog/we-shall-have-order

Comment: Thank you, you save my life.
I had missed this little detail on the operation of the "partition key" which sorts on the hash of the value.

Thank you for the link to your post and thank you for keeping the community alive.
Have a nice day